# what regex can I use to clean up automatically generated string that gets lots of new lines and tabs, etc

Tags: php, regex

[image]

I have to clean up this autogenerated string, what regex can I use to clean up some of this

so to give you clear example I need to go from this

```
body {\r\n
\r\n
            background-color: #7D7D7D;\r\n
    \r\n
    font-family: Oswald, Verdana, Arial;\r\n
    font-size: 16px;\r\n
    color: #2F84A5;\r\n
\r\n
            background-image: url("/uploads/2018/3/6/jasper-van-der-meij-757.jpg");\r\n
    }\r\n
\r\n
.main-layout .content {\r\n
            background-color: #A7E9F1;\r\n
    }\r\n
\r\n
```

to this

```
body {\r\n
    background-color: #7D7D7D;\r\n
    font-family: Oswald, Verdana, Arial;\r\n
    font-size: 16px;\r\n
    color: #2F84A5;\r\n
    background-image: url("/uploads/2018/3/6/jasper-van-der-meij-757.jpg");\r\n
}\r\n
\r\n
.main-layout .content {\r\n
    background-color: #A7E9F1;\r\n
}\r\n
\r\n
```

to make it even more clear from this

```
body {

            background-color: #7D7D7D;

    font-family: Oswald, Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2F84A5;

            background-image: url("/uploads/2018/3/6/jasper-van-der-meij-757.jpg");
    }

.main-layout .content {
            background-color: #A7E9F1;
    }
```

to this:

```
body {
    background-color: #7D7D7D;
    font-family: Oswald, Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2F84A5;
    background-image: url("/uploads/2018/3/6/jasper-van-der-meij-757.jpg");
}

.main-layout .content {
    background-color: #A7E9F1;
}
```

basically, I need to beautify the produced code, and do this in php prefarably using regex.

Do I need multiple regexes for this and do it in mutliple passes or can I use one complex regex.

How would I change 3 `\t` into just 1 `\t`, could someone give me that example as a start?

What I see that I need to do is

1. turn all

   `{\r\n`
   `\r\n`

   into  just

   `{\r\n`
2. turn multiple `\t` into single `\t`
3. if I find a line with `\t}` turn it into just `}`
4. remove empty lines if they are inside `{ }`

Anyone can give me a head start so I can start experimenting with this?

Comment: Replace `\\r\\n` with "" (blank string) and replace `[\t ]{2,}` with `\t`

Comment: Fix the title it's kinda long

Comment: Have you tried anything? A bit effort on it you would have come to [`\t+(?=})|(\R|\t)\1+`](https://regex101.com/r/GtU5aX/1)

Comment: hi Revo, yes I am playing around but to be honest I do not have to work with regex everyday so I am not a pro at it, thanks I will try that, actually I tried this right now in my code: $customizeCss = preg_replace('\t+(?=})|(\R|\t)\1+', '\1', $customizeCss); and I get this error: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: what should I use as a second parameter to preg_replace function?

Comment: You have to use delimiters in preg_* functions: `preg_replace('/\t+(?=})|(\R|\t)\1+/', '$1', $customizeCss);`

Comment: hmm just used that code and while it worked in the link you included above, my css still looks exactly the same as before... its like I didnt run any regex at all, wonder what happened

Comment: So your input string doesn't contain tabs as you thought. They may be space characters.

Comment: seems you are correct, what can I do about these extra spaces? to produce same end result you had in the link?

Comment: seems I should trim more then 4 spaces into just 4 spaces, so that would remove the extra long spaces, and then I would need to trim every space in front of each }

Comment: Like I wrote in the first comment, all you have to do is replace two or more tabs or spaces with a single tab.

Comment: You may do something like this `preg_replace('/^\h+(?=})|^(\h{4})\h*|(\R|\t)\2+/m', '$1$2', $customizeCss);`

Comment: great that did it, you see this is much better approach then the package below! :) I wish I could select this as the answer!

Comment: i get some glitches like 2 lines with just 4 spaces in each, but that is acceptable, I will try to get rid of that as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are CSS beautifiers out there that are supposed to handle these cases more properly even those you didn't have an idea about to list them. The other answer proposed one. But in order to come with a regex solution for covering those limited cases this would be one:

```
^(\h)(?(?!\h*})(\h{3}))\h*|(\R|\t)\3+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/F9OKCe/1)

Breakdown:

```
^   # Assert beginning of line
(\h)    # Match a horizental whitespace
(?(?!\h*})  # If it's not followed by a `}`
    (\h{3}) # Match 3 number of whitespaces
)   # End of conditional
\h* # Match any number of whitespaces
| # Or
(\R|\t)\3+  # Any kind of newline characters or tabs 
            # that occurs more than two times in a row
```

PHP code:

```
preg_replace('/^(\h)(?:\h*(?=})|(\h{3})\h*)|(\R|\t)\3+/m', '$1$2$3', $CSS);
```

### Update

Based on comments:

```
preg_replace('/^(?(?! *})( {4}))\h*|(?|(?<!})(?>(\R)\h*)+|(\t))\2+/m', '$1$2', $customizeCss);
```

Comment: close but it still left out some double empty lines and it did not create new line after }

here is the code that works for me right now and creates beautifed css code with no empty lines and new line after }

Comment: $customizeCss = preg_replace('/^\h+(?=})|^(\h{4})\h*|(\R|\t)\2+/m', '$1$2', $customizeCss);
            $customizeCss = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $customizeCss);
            $customizeCss = str_replace(['}'], ["}\r\n"], $customizeCss);

Comment: hi Revo, i didnt see it was you, so I posted my own answer, see it above and comment if you have anything more to add, for whoever reads this in future :)

Comment: This doesn't allow multi empty lines to be existed as seen here https://regex101.com/r/F9OKCe/2 (it's possible that the lines you are referring to as empty have some space characters) and you don't have to invoke multiple `preg_replace` functions that's a bad idea.

Comment: bad idea why? this piece of code will be run maybe once in a while, perhaps when user modifes the current theme, and perhaps never again, its not hard on the server :)

Comment: see this image or my comment below to see what I get with the your one line regex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rVw3.png for some reason still empty lines, and not one but mutiple...

Comment: Doing more than one `preg_replace` is most of the time a sign of bad design because it means who wrote them wasn't able to bundle up all of them into one, leading into an inefficient approach. Please check update.

Comment: well thank you for this lesson, I am eager to learn! most obliged! :)

Comment: btw I notice you have added some rules here like: ?<!}\s)  what does this do exactly? I already had new line after }, so I wanted two lines and managed to do that with my 2 passes of regex and third pass with str_replace, so after each } I got two \n so I am confused since you added } into regex it does not produce this, I get tightly coupled css rules instead of them being separated by one empty line. Its not a big deal, I am asking more to learn if this is what you also inteded it to do but for some reason its not doing this on my side.

Comment: This `(?<!}\s)` is a negative lookbehind to prevent matching a newline character after `}` but that could have failed on `\r\n` so I changed it. Please check update. Also I made a demo here https://regex101.com/r/F9OKCe/4

Answer (score 2):

Try [PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) to pretty print your CSS files.

Run `composer require sabberworm/php-css-parser`

If you want to format the output, pass an instance of type `Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat` or use one of the predefined formats

Sample code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser(file_get_contents('somefile.css'));
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();

echo $oCssDocument->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createPretty());
```

Comment: thanks but that would add one more package to the project, I would prefer to do it with some regex and not have to include a new package :)

Comment: Rated up, as this is the proper approach.

Comment: actually its not better approach, this package is too much if I can solve this with regex, not to mention that I do not want to add another package just for this...

Comment: You only have to use this package once if you want to update your CSS file. Its not like its loaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

tried some of suggested solutions above but had to do it in 3 passes, here is the code that beautifies the css

```
        $customizeCss = preg_replace('/^\h+(?=})|^(\h{4})\h*|(\R|\t)\2+/m', '$1$2', $customizeCss);
        $customizeCss = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $customizeCss);
        $customizeCss = str_replace(['}'], ["}\r\n"], $customizeCss);
```

this is the result

[image]

3 passes are needed since I am not good at regex to do it all in one line.

and this solution

```
preg_replace('/^(\h)(?:\h*(?=})|(\h{3})\h*)|(\R|\t)\3+/m', '$1$2$3', $CSS);
```

almost work but give this result

[image]